# Python Tkinter - frame weight problem using grid layout

Tags: python, tkinter, layout, grid, frame

`root` frame weight is correct when button `btnOpen` is not present (commented). Otherwise the weight of `root` and `frLeft` is about 1:1. Why button (or frame `frButtons`) makes a difference?
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("xxx")
root.geometry("500x400")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=15)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=10)

frLeft = Frame(root, bg="#808080")
frLeft.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

frRight = Frame(root, bg="#FAF0F0")
frRight.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")
frRight.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frButtons = Frame(frRight, bg="red")
frButtons.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=10)

btnOpen = Button(frButtons, command=open, text='Open', padx=2).grid(row=0, sticky="WS", padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Correct:

[image]

Not correct:

[image]

Comment: `weight` does not guarantee that all widgets get the required space.  Need to use `uniform=1` and `weight=...` together to enforce it.

Comment: Yes, `uniform` option helped, thanks!